pdf-lib: open links in new tab
I am trying to add links to a PDF document using the pdf-lib JavaScript library. When I open the PDF in a browser and click on a link, it opens the website, but it does so in the same browser tab. I would like it to open in a new tab. Does anyone know how to achieve this functionality?
export const drawLink = (
  x: number,
  y: number,
  item: TransformedEvent,
  haufefontSans: PDFFont,
  currentPage: PDFPage,
  pdfDoc: PDFDocument,
  linkImg: PDFImage
) => {
  if (getTexts.link(item).trim() === "nothing_to_link") {
    return y;
  } else {
    const linkAnnotation: PDFDict = pdfDoc.context.obj({
      Type: "Annot",
      Subtype: "Link",
      Rect: [x, y - 10, x + 150, y + 10],
      Border: [0, 0, 0],
      C: [0, 0, 1],
      A: {
        Type: "Action",
        S: "URI",
        URI: PDFString.of(getTexts.link(item).trim()),
        // NewWindow: true,  <-- this does not work.
      },
    });
    const linkAnnotationRef = pdfDoc.context.register(linkAnnotation);

    currentPage.drawText("mehr erfahren", {
      x: x + 18,
      y: y,
      size: 13,
      color: red,
      font: haufefontSans,
    });
    currentPage.drawImage(linkImg, {
      x: x + 2,
      y: y - 2,
      width: 11,
      height: 11,
    });
    y -= 13;

    let existingAnnots: PDFObject[] = [];
    const existingAnnotsObj = currentPage.node.get(PDFName.of("Annots"));
    if (existingAnnotsObj instanceof PDFArray) {
      existingAnnots = existingAnnotsObj.asArray().slice();
    } else if (existingAnnotsObj) {
      existingAnnots.push(existingAnnotsObj);
    }
    existingAnnots.push(linkAnnotationRef);
    currentPage.node.set(
      PDFName.of("Annots"),
      pdfDoc.context.obj(existingAnnots)
    );
    return y;
  }
};


There are generally 2 ways to write a hyperlink in ANY pdf to work with PDF readers.
From PDF Standard

PDF includes objects such as annotations and hypertext links that are not part of the page content itself
but are useful for interactive viewing and document interchange.


A uniform resource identifier (URI) is a string that identifies (resolves to) a resource on the Internet, typically a file that is the destination of a hypertext link, although it may also resolve to a query or
other entity. (URIs are described in Internet RFC 3986.)
A URI action causes a URI to be resolved. "Table 210 — Additional entries specific to a URI action"
shows the action dictionary entries specific to this type of action.

One is visible URL text (Deliberately with a gap here) such as
https: //stackoverflow.com/questions/78260497
Note how the editor (browser) creates its own hyperlink due to web viewer standards.
In a PDF there should never be a gap pdf-lib: open links in new tab but from the time of creation the user can choose for themselves what they do with a hyperlink, there is no action behind the text to enforce "go to tab" or "go to window" or even open link in a browser if the PDF viewer is a PDF reading editor.

The other type of hyperlink is a PDF action that does not require scripts as it too is built into the reader as attempt to go to a URL (https://) FROM this area of a page. Thus it is the user decides what method is used for that action, in the viewers settings.



Answer
Thus the DEFAULT URI relocation will replace the current viewport content. That may be a different "Page" in same PDF, or another Page in another PDF or a website, However by PDF design the default PDF "/Action" is in the same tab.
There are exotic "Scripted" attempts to popup secondary Modals with a separate viewport such as Media (allowed to a limited extent) or in past could be SWF driven. However these are actively discouraged and often not work in the majority of secured PDF viewers.
